# A question on measurable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is:

> Show that a positive function $ f $ on $ E $ is $ \varepsilon $-measurable if and only if it has the form
>   $$
> f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} I_{A_{n}}
> $$
>   for some sequence $ \{ a_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{R}}_{+} $ and some sequence $ \{ A_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq \varepsilon $.

I know that the absolute-value function from $ \overline{\mathbb{R}} $ to $ \overline{\mathbb{R}}_{+} $ is $ \varepsilon $-measurable when $ \varepsilon $ equals the Borel $ \sigma $-algebra on $ \overline{\mathbb{R}} $. But it doesn’t have the form
$$
f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} I_{A_{n}},
$$
since its image is uncountable. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Dear Yangzhe, I edited your question to make it clearer. I hope you don’t mind! :)

Comment: @HaskellCurry: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $x\mapsto \sum_n a_n \, I_{A_n}(x)$ can be uncountable.  Given $x\in E$, each choice of whether $x$ does or does not belong to $A_1$, whether $x$ does or does not belong to $A_2$, $\dots$, produces a different subset of the $a_n$s to sum.  Since there are countably infinitely many choices, each of which can be made in two different ways, this permits the range of $x\mapsto \sum_n a_n\,  I_{A_n}(x)$ to have cardinality up to $2^{\aleph_0}$.  This is the cardinality of all of $\overline {\Bbb R}_+$, so there is no cardinality restriction on the range which prevents you from getting all measurable functions in the given way.